# Gimp switch color channels

Tags: framebuffer, gimp

I'm capturing a raw framebuffer on an embedded device.  The framebuffer is 32bit BGRA color mode

```
cp /dev/fb0 framebuffer.data
```

I can transfer the raw dump to my PC and import it into GIMP, but GIMP only allows me to read the raw data as if it were ARGB, which results in incorrect colors.  Is there a way to just switch the red and blue channels in GIMP?

Answer (score 2):

What you could try in GIMP is to use the channel mixer - it allows to mix new RGB components  out of the image's original RGB  components.

In the screenshot, I've taken a simple image with a red, green and a blue column, and told the channel mixer to turn red into green, green into blue and blue into red. Original colors are shown in the lower half, transformed ones in the upper half of the image.

[image: Channel mixer apploied on a simple red, green and blue image - orginal colors in the lower half, transformed in the upper half]

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was looking for!  The gstreamer implementation actually turned out to be faster for me though since I can run one command without having to open an external program

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around this by using gstreamer to convert the color and do the screencap...

```
#!/bin/bash

cp /dev/fb0 /home/root/framebuffer.data
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="/home/root/framebuffer.data" ! rawvideoparse use-sink-caps=false width=800 height=1280 format=bgra  ! imxvideoconvert_ipu !  videoconvert ! pngenc snapshot=false compression-level=1 ! filesink location=/home/root/screencap.png
rm /home/root/framebuffer.data
```